# Cómo puedo ejecutar un servidor express y un front react desde un sólo comando? Es posible?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

Tengo una pequeña app en node (que ha de escalar) corriendo un servidor express con las primeras rutas, luego comencé a construír un fron en react. Tanto front como back funcionan y se comunican bien. Hasta ahora ejecuto las dos cosas por separado, o las tres. 1) El servidor MySQL en xampp 2) El servidor express y 3) React.
El motivo de la consula es que cuando esto pase a producción debería ejecutarse con un sólo comando, y he ahí mi ignorancia, cómo se hace?
Agradezco cualquier sugerencia, link para leer o correctivo...

Comment: ¿Porqué en un solo comando? ¿Qué se ejecutará primero en ese único comando y porqué? Si debes reiniciar 1 sólo componente se reinician todos los demás? Hablas de "escalado", ¿cómo lo harías teniendo 1 sólo comando para iniciar los componentes?

Comment: Supongo que lo lógico sería emplear un archivo que encapsule la secuencia de comandos de modo que primero se arranque el servidor MySQL, luego el servidor express y finalmente el start de react.